# unexpected 'expecting kEND'

Tags: ruby

here is the code that is supposed to give a deck of cards:

```
class Cards
attr_accessor :value, :color

    def initialize(value, color)
    @value = value
    @color = color
end

end



2.upto(14) do |number|
recent = number
    1.upto(4) do |value|
        case value
        when 1
            color = :Spades
        when 2
            color = :Clubs
        when 3
            color = :Hearts
        when 4
            color = :Diamonds
        end             
        #{recent}of#{color} = Cards.new(recent, color)
        puts "#{recent}of#{color}"
    end
end
```

and it works fine. but as i try to add this line:

```
deck << #{recent}of#{color}
```

after

```
puts '#{recent}of#{color}'
```

suddenly a wild error appears!

```
poker.rb:29: syntax error, unexpected kEND
```

and i dont have the slightest idea how this line, which moves objects into an array can cause it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think you realize it, but the following line is a *comment*, and is completely ignored during execution (this is the only reason this line “works”):

```
#{recent}of#{color} = Cards.new(recent, color)
```

You cannot interpolate when defining a local variable. In fact, you cannot dynamically define a local variable at all in Ruby (well, not in 1.9+).

More broadly, you cannot just have open interpolation (like you’re trying to do with `deck << #{recent}of#{color}`)—interpolation can *only* occur within a double-quoted string (or equivalent structure) or a regular expression.

Instead just shovel the new card directly into the deck:

```
deck << Cards.new(recent, color)
```

Comment: perfect, exactly what i meant

Answer (score 0):

You need double quotation marks or string literals to use string interpolation:

```
deck << "#{recent}of#{color}"
```

or

```
deck << %(#{recent}of#{color})
```

Comment: this way i'm gonna have deck array full of strings, i need Cards objects to go there, not strings